# Android Sqlite Monthly summary of datas

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm developing home budget app. In this, I had two tables in database. One table for income and another one for expenses. In the Expense table, i have three column to get data from user that is, expense amt, category, date. I'm using Date Picker to get date from user and I have saved user entered date into database expense table.

I need to display data according to month. Let say now we are in December i need to display all transaction of December. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Can you show us sample data from your date column?

Comment: public static final String TABLE_NAME="user";
 public static final String KEY_FNAME="fname";
 public static final String KEY_LNAME="lname";
    public static final String DATE="date";

Comment: public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+KEY_FNAME+" INTEGER, "+KEY_LNAME+" INTEGER, "+DATE+" TEXT)";

Comment: Here is the sample of DB.

Comment: What is your date format in `DATE` column?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get that with

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE strftime('%m', COLUMN_DATE) = '04' //04 = month number, which here is MAY.
```

Hope this helps, :)

Comment: I tried this query it runs without error but it doesn't display anything

Comment: My date format: SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy"); ex(16 December 2016)

Comment: Maybe because there are no records for the month 04.

Comment: I added record for month 04 still it doesn't display